# how to accept a clang_complete match?

Tags: clang-complete

I was trying out the vim [clang_complete](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete/blob/master/doc/clang_complete.txt) plugin.  Once I type the C-x C-u on the following code fragment, positioned after `some` below

```
inline void someSizeChecks()
{
   // ...
}

void foo()
{
   some
}
```

I get a selection menu like:

[image: completion menu]

Gui challenged question: How do I select the function that the clang_complete plugin spits out in this pink selection menu?  I tried space, enter, f, and tab.  I also don't see anything in the plugin docs on how to use the menus once presented.

Answer (score 1):

You select the option using CTRL-N and CTRL-P and select it using CTRL-Y.

Answer (score 0):

It was in the help:

```
                                        *g:clang_complete_auto*
If equal to 1, automatically complete after ->, ., ::
Default: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

At that point, you could either use the arrows of your keyboard, or use C-n and C-p to browse through the list of completion results.

Comment: When there's a list I can figure out how to do it.  When there was only one match, it wasn't obvious.

Answer (score 0):

In order to select items in the menu generated by clang_complete you simply need to use the **up** and **down** keys to make your select your choice, finally hit **enter** to finish the completion.